# justify-content to center using Flex Box

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm trying to align my div to the center of the page but I can't figure how to do it using the justify option.

this is how it looks like now:
[image: how it looks like now]

html:

```
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="box" *ngFor='let movie of moviesArray;let i=index'>
    ....
  </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin:0 auto;

}

.box{
    width:80%;
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    margin:10px 0;
    padding:20px;

}



....
```

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in `flex-direction: column`, the main axis switches to vertical alignment, and `justify-content` works up/down, not left/right.

Use `align-items` to center horizontally when in `flex-direction: column`.

More details here: [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin:0 auto;

}

.box{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width:80%;
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    margin:10px 0;
    padding:20px;

}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="box" *ngFor='let movie of moviesArray;let i=index'>
    ..................
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: add box class to display: flex ,justify-content for centering horizontally, and align-items for centering vertically